# Descriptive URL, different pages, but same controller ( domain.com/cars/wheels)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, routes, nested-routes

Custom routes for the same controller. I have many semi-static pages in my app (actually stored in my database with a group and page name field), they are grouped by product and then subject, for example
Cars: tires, Wheels, Radio, Windshield
Homes: Doors, Windows, Roof
Products and Services: data services

I would prefer not to make a new controller for each group.  However, I am trying to get different URL paths that are descriptive.  For example:

```
domain.com/cars/tires_and_spokes
domain.com/cars/wheels
domain.com/homes/doors_and_knobs
domain.com/homes/windows
domain.com/products_and_services/data_service
```

currently, all I have is

```
domain.com/pages/cars_tires_and_spokes
etc.
```

but I prefer the former.

Routes:

```
   pages_from_DB =[ 
           {group:"cars", name:"tires and spokes"}
           {group:"cars", name:"wheels"}
           {group:"homes", name:"tires and spokes"}
           {group:"homes", name:"windows"}
           ]
   pages = %w[
               cars_tires_and_spokes
               cars_wheels
               homes_doors_and_knobs
               homes_windows
               products_and_services_data_service
             ]

   pages.each do |page|          
     get page, controller: "pages", action: page
   end
```

Controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

   pages_from_DB =[ 
       {group:"cars", name:"tires and spokes"}
       {group:"cars", name:"wheels"}
       {group:"homes", name:"tires and spokes"}
       {group:"homes", name:"windows"}
       ]
   pages = %w[
               cars_tires_and_spokes
               cars_wheels
               homes_doors_and_knobs
               homes_windows
               products_and_services_data_service
             ]

  pages.each do |page|          
    define_method(page) do 

    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've missed the point of [`nested resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :groups, path: "", only: [] do
   resources :pages, path: "" #-> url.com/:group_id/:id
end
```

This will direct any user to the `pages` controller, to which they're able to pull both the `Group` and `ID` from their respective models:

```
#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @group = Group.find params[:group_id]
      @page  = @group.pages.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

--

This should be accompanied by the following models:

```
#app/models/group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :pages
end

#app/models/page.rb
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :group
end
```

If you wanted to treat the routes with a [`slug`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug) (instead of `id`), you'll want to look at [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id):

```
#Gemfile
gem "friendly_id"

$ rails generate friendly_id
$ rails generate scaffold group title:string slug:string:uniq
$ rails generate scaffold page title:string slug:string:uniq 
$ rake db:migrate

#app/models/group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :pages

   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end

#app/models/page.rb
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :group

   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

This will allow you to use:

```
<%= link_to group_pages_path(@group, @page) %>
# -> url.com/group-name/page-title
```

---

**Update**

The above code was based on the idea that you would be able to put your `pages` into the database (as you should). If you don't want to do that, there is a [`wildcard route`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments) you *may* be able to use:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "*group/:page", to: "pages#show"
```

If the pages were "semi-static" (still don't know what that means), you'd then be able to render the various views as required:

```
#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      group = params[:group]
      render "#{params[:group]}/#{params[:page]"
   end
end
```

The above would give you the following link:

```
 url.com/path/to/your/group/this-is-the-page-id
```

Depending on your group / sub-group structure, it should give you the ability to call the various *views*. I don't agree with it but it's apparently what you wanted.

--

**Custom Middleware**

We also created custom middleware which has *some* of the functionality for this:

```
#config/routes.rb
get "*group/:page", to: PageDispatcher.new

#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   cattr_accessor :pages #-> PagesController.pages
   @@pages = %w[
               cars_tires_and_spokes
               cars_wheels
               homes_doors_and_knobs
               homes_windows
               products_and_services_data_service
             ]
end

#lib/page_dispatcher.rb
class PageDispatcher

  #Init
  def initialize(router)
    @router = router
  end

  #Env
  def call(env)
    group    = env["action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"][:group]
    page     = env["action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"][:page]
    if PagesController.pages.include? page
      strategy(slug).call(@router, env)
    else
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end
  end

  ##########################################

  private

  #Strategy
  def strategy(url)
    Render.new(url)
  end

  ####################

  #Render
  class Render

    def initialize(url)
      @url = url
    end

    def call(router, env)
      controller  = PagesController 
      action      = "show"
      controller.action(action).call(env)
    end

  end

  ####################

end
```

Comment: I have semi-static pages, they don't get pulled from the database. The nested resources part is useful, but I need to figure out how to adapt to static pages.

Comment: When you say "semi-static", what do you mean?

Comment: You meant they're populated with data set in the controller (not tied to a model)?

Comment: To simplify things, think of all the pages as completely-static.  If you look at my controller, I reference methods corresponding to the view name.  As for the groups and categories, they could be listed in a hash like above, no database needed.  I hope this helps

Comment: Sure, I just figured that if they were completely static, it would be far better to put them into the `pages` db, so that you just have to call the `show` action. That's why I posted what I did. I'll add a refactor for you now

Comment: Updated for you, both recommendations route to the `PagesController`

Comment: My pages tended to be completely different, with video or pictures, forms in different places.  Which is why I made static pages that pages_controller would serve.  I will look into adding "Tinymce" a WYSIWYG HTML editor to my activeadmin to store the contents of each page. and review your recommendation. thank you

Comment: No problem, it is by far better to use database-stored data than hard-coded.